# How do I send data to an XBee in the network?

Tags: controller, processor, xbee, zigbee

I'm using a [ZigBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) network with 10 XBee S2 modules. One XBee is connected to the processor which will mainly send data to other XBees. I want to send different data to different XBees. How is that possible? How can I send data to any particular XBee?

Answer (score 0):

To send data to a particular xbee, we use 64-bit address of that xbee as destination (DH+DL). You will find the address behind xbee. If you are using xbees in API mode, destinations can be put in frames. it would be recommended to use xbee connected to processor be in API mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.